# How to query other namespaces via Tooling API (REST)

Tags: tooling-api

In the [Tooling API Guide entry for `AutoResponseRule`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_autoresponserule.htm?q=mns), it says

> More information about the autoresponse rule is available by querying the metadata type AutoResponseRules or AutoResponse in the metadata namespace (mns).

Which lead me to [Tooling API Objects and Namespaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_overview.htm), which lists four namespaces from the Tooling API WSDL, including `metadata.tooling.soap.sforce.com`, with the prefix `mns`.

This seems to imply that you can fetch (at lease some?) Metadata types via Tooling API via the `mns` namespace, but I can find no examples of such.  Additionally, I can't find any reference to accessing alternate namespaces via REST.  I tried a simple guess based on the Tooling API AutoResponse docs linked above, with this Tooling API query:

```
SELECT Id, Name from mns__AutoResponseRules
```

but of course I got the expected "sObject type mns__AutoResponseRules' is not supported" error, and the same without the `mns__` prefix.  So what do the docs mean by "querying the metadata type AutoResponseRules or AutoResponse in the metadata namespace (mns)," and is such an operation possible via the Tooling API's REST version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just using extra 's' in sobject name. you can try

```
select id from AutoResponseRule
```

Comment: Sadly, no; see my first link.  The Tooling API object is `AutoResponseRule` (singular), but "More information about the autoresponse rule is available by querying the metadata type AutoResponseRules [Plural] or AutoResponse in the metadata namespace (mns)."  I have also confirmed this by retrieving `AutoResponseRules` (plural) using Metadata API.  But I remain curious if there is a way to use (REST) Tooling API to fetch additional Metadata API info via the "mns" namespace.